# Can 'Triangle Away' reset knox counter to 0×0?

Tags: samsung-knox

I have a galaxy s5 duos (SM-G900FD) and my knox counter olis triggered to 0×1 (4) (due to some rooting and blah blah..) is it possible to reset knox to 0×0 with triangle away of any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is **IMPOSSIBLE** to reset the KNOX flag to `0x0` or `0`.  Triangle away will only reset the flashcounter and will not reset the Knox flag.

Hope my answer helps